# Windows UWP App FileNotFoundException at XamlTypeInfo.g.cs

Tags: c#, uwp

I am developing a simple `Windows UWP app` that runs fine on the desktop. However, when I try to debug it on mobile either emulator or device. I get the following error in `XamlTypeInfo.g.cs` file.

```
public global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IXamlType GetXamlType(string fullName)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fullName); // added this line to get file name
            if(_provider == null)
            {
                _provider = new global::ContosoCabs.UWP.ContosoCabs_UWP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider();
            }
            return _provider.GetXamlTypeByName(fullName);
        }
```

The error is

`An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in App.UWP.exe but was not handled in user code`

`Additional information: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

The file name that is not found : `Windows.Foundation.IReference1<Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation.Peers.AccessibilityView>`

I am not able to figure out what that file is as it running fine on Desktop. Any suggestions are welcome. TIA!

Comment: Clean the solution then rebuild it. It should work fine.

Comment: Tried it many times. Still the issue persists.

Comment: What build of Mobile are you using? What build of Desktop?

Comment: I am using the same build variant x86

Comment: That's not what Peter is asking for. 
You can use the “winver” tool to find the build number of your Windows 10 system. To launch it, you can tap the Windows key, type “winver” into the Start menu, and press Enter OR press Windows Key + R, type “winver” into the Run dialog, and press Enter.

The second line here will tell you which build of Windows 10 you have.

Comment: Both the emulator and desktop are running on the RS1 build version 1607 (OS Build 14379.0)